# Possible bug in data

Tags: support

Can someone take a look at this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5193/507)?

I can honestly tell you that I do not recall ever answering this question. As well, per the comment, it has no relation to the question what so ever.

Comment: That definitely looks wrong. I'll take a closer look later today.

Comment: Presumably you were answering the part of the question `Is there any tool that could find the objects using the date and time?`

Comment: If it's a bug in the database, it's quite ironic that it's on DBA.SE. :)

Comment: @MartinSmith that is what I thought when I looked at it but just wanted to make sure, and I guess most may look at his first question.

Comment: Actually yeah it makes sense now after re-reading a couple of times, though the answer should explicitly call out "commands that use a local time zone, like `GETDATE` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`." I'll edit that in (and if you don't like it you can roll it back :-)).

Comment: @AaronBertrand looks good to me, thanks.